# How to maintain an Excel or Libra-office calc sheet for nested JSON or nested XML convertion

Tags: xml, json, excel, mongodb

I want to maintain a record for my MongoDB instance in Excel or LibreOffice Calc, but the problem is that I am not able to do that. I am able to handle a single record, but how do I handle nested data?

Answer (score 0):

Excel can't handle nested data, therefore this is not solvable in a nice way. The easiest way to handle it would be to take a nested structure like this:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": "c"
  },
  "d": "e"
}
```

and convert it into a table like this:

```
| a.b  | d   |
|------|-----|
| c    | e   |
```